# WPF tabitem positioning

Tags: wpf, tabs, controls, position, tabitem

What is the proper way of positioning for example three tabitems at the very top left corner and one at the very top right corner of a tab control using WPF?

I have tried to move the fourth tabitem to the right by changing its margin but this doesn't produce a good result; first of all it is cut short and second of all it does not display correctly when selected.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is that the [TabPanel](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.tabpanel.aspx), which is used internally by the TabControl to lay out the tabs, does not seem to support what you want. A quick workaround would be to replace the TabPanel by something else, for example, a DockPanel:

```
<Window x:Class="Window1"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="Window1" Height="300" Width="300">
    <TabControl>
        <TabControl.Template>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="TabControl">
                <Grid>
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <Border BorderThickness="0,0,1,1" BorderBrush="#D0CEBF" Grid.Row="1">
                        <Border BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" 
                                BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}">
                            <Border Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                                <ContentPresenter ContentSource="SelectedContent"/>
                            </Border>
                        </Border>
                    </Border>
                    <DockPanel IsItemsHost="True" LastChildFill="False" Margin="2,2,2,0" />
                </Grid>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </TabControl.Template>

        <TabItem Header="Item 1" />
        <TabItem Header="Item 2" />
        <TabItem Header="Item 3" />
        <TabItem Header="Item 4" DockPanel.Dock="Right" />
    </TabControl>
</Window>
```

(Reference: This is a modified version of an [MSDN example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752038.aspx) for styling a TabControl.)

The simple DockPanel doesn't work as smooth as the TabPanel -- the tabs "jump" a bit when switching between them, but this might get you started. Maybe subclassing the TabPanel and overriding the relevant parts would give you a more accurate result; I guess it depends on how much effort you want to put into this.

Answer (score 2):

I found that by inserting an "invisible" tab I could adjust the spacing, (i.e. move the tabs down from the top)

For example:

```
TabItem  Height="100"  Visibility="Hidden" <br>
TabItem..... <br>
TabItem....  <br>
```

Answer (score 0):

You would need to swap out the [TabPanel](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.tabpanel.aspx) within the TabControl to something custom which provided the desired behavior. None of the default [panels](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms754152.aspx) are going to provide your desired behavior out of the box.

This will most likely need to involve overriding [MeasureOverride](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.measureoverride.aspx) and [ArrangeOverride](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.arrangeoverride.aspx) to provide the custom placement within the panel that is desired based on the number of items it contains.

Answer (score 0):

This will involve a custom ControlTemplate for the TabControl. I tried an example using a DockPanel as the items host rather than the default TabPanel.

```
<Style  TargetType="{x:Type TabControl}">
        <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle"
                Value="True" />
        <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels"
                Value="True" />
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type TabControl}">
                    <Grid KeyboardNavigation.TabNavigation="Local">
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <DockPanel Name="HeaderPanel"
                                   LastChildFill="False"
                                  Grid.Row="0"
                                  Panel.ZIndex="1"
                                  Margin="0,0,4,-1"
                                  IsItemsHost="True"
                                  KeyboardNavigation.TabIndex="1"
                                  Background="Transparent" />
                        <Border Name="Border"
                                Grid.Row="1"
                                Background="WhiteSmoke"
                                BorderBrush="Black"
                                BorderThickness="1"
                                CornerRadius="2"
                                KeyboardNavigation.TabNavigation="Local"
                                KeyboardNavigation.DirectionalNavigation="Contained"
                                KeyboardNavigation.TabIndex="2">
                            <ContentPresenter Name="PART_SelectedContentHost"
                                              Margin="4"
                                              ContentSource="SelectedContent" />
                        </Border>
                    </Grid>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

The problem is that I don't know of a way of exposing the DockPanel.Dock property to the TabItems outside of the ControlTemplate E.G.

```
<TabControl Margin="10">
    <TabItem Header="Tab One" DockPanel.Dock="Left"/>
    <TabItem Header="Tab Two" DocKPanel.Dock="Left"/>
    <TabItem Header="Tab Three" DocKPanel.Dock="Left"/>
    <TabItem Header="Tab Four" DocKPanel.Dock="Right"/>
</TabControl>

// Note: This does not work!!
```

I guess you will need to write your own Panel to host the TabItems; Note that this will be quite a lot of work as you will need to handle things like overflow behaviour which is built into the TabPanel.

Even if you did try this I think you would have to write a custom *TabControl* if you wanted to expose this functionality outside of the ControlTemplate.

If you want to go down this road then see my answer in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2110930/wpf-tabcontrol-controltemplate/4716341#4716341)